# Как здесь расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Однако чтобы определить, какие из них следует оценивать для адекватного выбора материала необходимо также знать силы и характер деформации, воздействующие на уплотнение в процессе эксплуатации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однако***,*** чтобы определить, какие из них следует оценивать для адекватного выбора материала***,*** необходимо также знать силы и характер деформации, воздействующие на уплотнение в процессе эксплуатации.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы ещё слова переставил - вряд ли можно сказать, что на уплотнение "действует характер деформации" (так сейчас следует из объединяющего оборота). Деформация, скорее, результат воздействия; в конструкции конкретного типа она может иметь характер, напр., сплющивания. Можно так изменить: "... силы, воздействующие на уплотнение, и характер его деформации в процессе эксплуатации."